# How to read flash video in Iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flash

Here is my problem, I would like to play flash video in my iphone app.
I'm parsing XML file and I get flash video url like this : http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xg8evw_electric-pursuit-english-version_auto

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: This can't be done. The iPhone doesn't support Flash.  If you have access to the video itself you should probably try and encode it in a video format that the iphone does support (most likely some h264 format). I'm no an iPhone/objective-c dev so maybe someone else will have a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks but I can't encode my video in an other format.

Comment: Your video is not encoded in "Flash." Flash is not a video encoding format, it is (when used for video) a container for a video of some type. While it is impossible to run Flash on an iOS device, it might be possible to play the type of video that is contained in your Flash document. (For example, a lot of YouTube video is, at the moment, H.264 underneath the Flash.)

Comment: @John: Flash is not a video format or a container, it's a browser plugin. FLV is a container format used chiefly by Flash - that might be what you have in mind? However, these days for most "flash video", the actual video stream is MP4 or the like, so the exact same stream can be read directly into an iPhone app, Android app,  most standalone video players, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!
Dailymotion added a new feature which generates an iframe compatible with Ipad, Iphone and Android.

Go on video page,
Click on Embed button (under video)
Check the checkbox Enable iframe player compatible iPhone, iPad, Android ... (Beta)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your video on the page is encoded as an H.264 MP4, so you can pull it in directly - http://vid.akm.dailymotion.com/video/693/662/27266396_mp4_h264_aac_hq_2.mp4?aksessionid=-1459231571_739074&akauth=1295628091_ff040ccd7dbe1834e6127da452a4069d (that's your video path)